# Magento 2 : Showing incorrect title and heading for certain pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, page-title

In Magento 2 some of the pages show incorrect title and heading, it is showing **Create New Customer Account** as Page heading and title for Contact page, advanced search page.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Have you added Customer Registration forms to any of these pages?

Comment: @V.S no, but I have used Social Login Plugin which show registration popup on all pages, including these pages , but the title are incorrect on only these pages